# Excel VBA Moving Picture with loop Increment by 2

Tags: excel, vba, image, loops

In Excel I have an add-on button that creates a QR code. However, the qr code is not on the right position that's why I would like to move it via VBA.

I have recorded the Macro to see what the code does and I realized that once the QR code image is created it gets a name (in this case "Picture 22". I need to create further QR codes and every time I execute the add-on button, the name of the picture changes (Picture 24, Picture 26, Picture 28 => Increment by +2).

I suppose the picture name needs to be set dynamically but I don't know how. I thought of getting the the name dynamically (e.g. "Picture"&) or a loop?

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 22")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 112.0588188976
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 155.2940944882
```

Comment: If the code just select the most recent picture in the spreadsheet, does it work for you? It seems to me a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion by @FernandoBarbosa, the following code will refer to the last image inserted on the active worksheet...

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        .IncrementLeft 112.0588188976
        .IncrementTop 155.2940944882
    End With
End With
```

Comment: I pasted the following, but it does not work yet:

Sub QR_Moving()

With ActiveSheet
    With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        .IncrementLeft 112.0588188976
        .IncrementTop 155.2940944882
    End With
End With

End Sub

Comment: When you say that "it does not work", what do you mean exactly?  Do you get an error?  If so, which one?